# Error within my code how can I centre responsive image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What error is in my code trying to make an image responsive and centre it however, I can't seem to successfully do it. What am I doing wrong? Example of how it looks on my screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYf8m.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <a href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" target="_blank">
           <img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" alt="picture" class="img-responsive center-block" />
         </a>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no problem with your current code, please show relevant code https://jsfiddle.net/gkk4ghgh/

Comment: Apologies I made a mistake, https://jsfiddle.net/1uzwcyka/1/ if I run this code on a 24inch monitor on google chrome the image of me isn't in the centre?

Comment: Run the code in the new updated post doesn't work? http://imgur.com/a/bqrKw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to add `col-lg-12` in order to center for large desktops.

```css
body .jumbotron {
  background-color: #01BAEF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Find out more about me!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-12">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h3>Who am I?</h3>
          <p>My name is Liam Docherty and I'm 17 years old, currently studying at Hackney Community College. In 2016 when I was taking my GCSE exams, I found my passion which was IT. My favourite topic within IT is software development. The reason how I
            found out this was my main passion with IT is because, I was assigned a task which was to create a website advertising myself to potential employees and really enjoyed learning multiple programming languages.</p>
          <p>Overall, I have multiple experience within a range of different sectors within IT. For example, I have knowledge of installing and maintaining hardware and software in a technology system. Moreover, I have experience using application software
            such as Adobe Photoshop CS6, Adobe Premier Pro CS6 and Adobe Illustrator CS6.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h3>Skills I can offer</h3>
          <p>Front-end Development</p>
          <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Installing and maintaining hardware such as</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Upgrading RAM</li>
            <li>Installing network card</li>
            <li>Using air duster to reduce dust build up in fan component</li>
          </ul>

          <p>Installing and maintaining software such as </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Installing an operating system</li>
            <li>Installing anti-virus application software</li>
            <li>Doing a defragment on hard drive</li>
          </ul>

          <p>Experience using application software such as...</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Adobe Photoshop CS6</li>
            <li>Adobe Premier Pro CS6</li>
            <li>Adobe Illustrator CS6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h3>Future goals within IT</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Improve my skills on using programming language javascript</li>
            <li>Learn how to use Adobe After Effects to improve editing skills</li>
            <li>Expand my knowledge on bootstrap</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! How can I scale down the image and make the outside border fit around the actual image?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use offset to center the image.

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <a href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" target="_blank">
       <img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" alt="picture" class="img-responsive center-block" />
     </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```